# Unable to change solc version used by dapp tools

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, dapptools

I am using ubuntu 21 LTS version and trying to compile and run pickle.finance contracts using dapp.tools. The steps are mentioned here https://github.com/pickle-finance/protocol. I followed till the command dapp build upon which it gave me different compiler version error. But that was because dapp was using solc version 0.8.6 whereas the contracts needed to be compiled which version 0.6. I used these two commands:

```
dapp --use solc:0.6.0 build
nix-env -f https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/archive/master.tar.gz -iA solc-static-versions.solc_0_6_0
```

to try to make dapp use verion 6 but after running dapp -version it still gives the following output

```
dapp 0.35.0

solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface

Version: 0.8.6+commit.11564f7e.Linux.g++

hevm 0.49.0
```

I also tried specifying the version in **dapprc** file but that doesn't work as well.

I need help on how to make it use version 6. Attaching screenshot of some of the errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The version of your compiler is different from your source file.
You need to install this specific version https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.7

or even better you can install `solc-select` https://github.com/crytic/solc-select and select the version of your choice